# javax.mail resulting in Authentication Exception in Linux, works normally in Windows

Tags: java, linux, authentication, email, smtp

I have a working React/Spring Boot app that sends e-mails via JavaMail, running on Windows.
I'm trying to make it run in a Linux server, but the very same credentials that work in Windows are generating `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure`

The JavaMailSender properties are defined here:

```
if(mailSender==null) {
            
            JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
            sender.setHost("mail.emailserver.com.br");
            sender.setPort(465);

            Properties props = sender.getJavaMailProperties();
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.mime.charset", "utf-8");
            
            mailSender = sender;
        }
        
        //Setting the credentials
        ((JavaMailSenderImpl) mailSender).setUsername(config.getEmail()+Configuracao.SERVIDOR_EMAIL); //this will result in something like "user@emailserver.com.br"
        ((JavaMailSenderImpl) mailSender).setPassword(new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode((config.getSenha().getBytes())), "UTF-8"));
```

I've checked, double checked and triple checked the credentials.
I'm also using the same JDK both in Windows and Linux.
I've tried setting encoding as UTF-8 thinking something odd may be happening with the special characters in the password, but everything seems to be OK up to the point the info is sent to the email server.

Thanks in advance!